# Number of possible permutations of n1 1's, n2 2's, n3 3's, n4 4's such that no two adjacent elements are same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

Given $n_1 $ number of  $1 $'s,  $n_2 $ number of  $2 $'s,  $n_3 $ number of  $3 $'s,  $n_4 $ number of  $4 $'s.

form a sequence using all these numbers such that two adjacent numbers should not be same.

I have tries lot of things but nothing worked.

can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hell.. this remembered to me the problem of four-color map.

Comment: @Masacroso Like a map with countries forming a belt and  with the determined number of countries with assigned color.  And  this number makes a difference. In the case for example 100 color_1 countries and 1 color_2,3,4 countries the proper coloring is impossible.

Answer (score 8):

**Generalisation**

Given a set called an alphabet $\{1, 2,\ldots , n\}$, the number of arrangements of $k_1$ $1$s, $k_2$ $2$s, ..., $k_n$ $n$s such that no two adjacent elements are the same is given by

> $$A(k_1,k_2,\ldots , k_n)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{k_i}L_{k_i}^{(-1)}(t)\: dt\tag{*}\label{*}$$

where

$$L_{k_i}^{(\alpha)}(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{k_i}(-1)^j\dbinom{k_i+\alpha}{k_i-j}\frac{t^{j}}{j!}$$

are Modified Laguerre Polynomials.

**Explanation**

Consider a regular expression $R$ (see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184722/order-of-characters/2185400#2185400) for more details on regular expressions)  that generates all words using our alphabet such that no two identical letters are adjacent.

Also consider the regular expressions $R_i$ for valid words ending with letter $i$. Then we must have

$$R=\epsilon+\sum_{i=1}^{n}R_i$$

where $\epsilon$ is the empty word.

Now, any valid word that ends in an $\textbf{i}$ must be a valid word that does not end in a $\textbf{i}$ with an $\textbf{i}$ appended hence

$$R_i=(R-R_i)\textbf{i}$$

Then the generating function equivalents of the regular expressions are

$$g(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n)$$

or simply

$$g=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_i$$

and

$$g_i=(g-g_i)x_i$$
$$\implies g_i=\frac{gx_i}{1+x_i}$$

then we have the generating function

$$g=1+g\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}$$
$$\implies g=\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\right)^{-1}$$

Then we have that the desired count is the coefficient $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{k_i}$ in $g$, in other words

\begin{align}
A(k_1,k_2,\ldots k_n)&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{k_i}\right]g\\
&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{k_i}\right]\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\right)^{-1}
\tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}

Now, it is straightforward to prove that for some function $f=f(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}e^{tf}\: dt=\frac{1}{1-f}\tag{2}\label{2}$$

by performing a Taylor expansion of $e^{tf}$ in $t$ and noting that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^r=r!$$

for $r\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

So we may, in fact express $\eqref{1}$ using $\eqref{2}$

$$\begin{align}
A(k_1,k_2,\ldots k_n)&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{k_i}\right]\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\exp\left(t\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\right)\: dt\\
&=\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{k_i}\right]\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\exp\left(t\cdot\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\right)\: dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^{n}[x_i^{k_i}]\exp\left(t\cdot\frac{x_i}{1+x_i}\right)\: dt
\tag{3}\label{3}\end{align}$$

The next thing we will need is the generating function for $(-1)^lL_l^{(-1)}(t)$, we can show it is

$$\begin{align}\exp\left(\frac{ty}{1+y}\right)&=\sum_{j\ge 0}\frac{(-t)^j}{j!}\left(\frac{-y}{1+y}\right)^j\\ 
&=\sum_{j\ge 0}(-1)^j\frac{t^j}{j!}\sum_{l\ge j}(-1)^l\binom{l-1}{l-j}y^l\\ 
&=\sum_{l\ge 0}y^l(-1)^l\left(\sum_{j=0}^{l}\frac{1}{j!}(-1)^j\binom{l-1}{l-j}t^j\right)\\
&=\sum_{l\ge 0}y^l(-1)^lL_l^{(-1)}(t) \end{align}$$

Hence

$$[y^l]\exp\left(\frac{ty}{1+y}\right)=(-1)^lL_l^{(-1)}(t)$$

Thus, substituting this into $\eqref{3}$ for $y=x_i$

$$A(k_1,k_2,\ldots k_n)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{k_i}L_{k_i}^{(-1)}(t) \: dt$$

As asserted.

As an example consider the simple case of the alphabet $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $k_1=4,\, k_2=3,\, k_3=3,\, k_4=2$ then

$$\begin{align}A(4,3,3,2)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\left(\frac{1}{24}t^4-\frac{1}{2}t^3+\frac{3}{2}t^2-t\right)\left(\frac{1}{6}t^3-t^2+t\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2-t\right)\: dt\\
&=23\,254
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice answer. (+1) I see you are a generatingfunctionologist. :-) I used this approach also for *[this related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349130/arranging-identical-balls/2349502#2349502)* answer.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusScheuer! I had to add my (+1) to your *related answer*. It seems that, despite this method being used several times here on MSE, many users are still relatively unaware of it's power. I'm trying to improve my understanding of generatingfunctionology and I have to say that many of your answers have been instrumental in helping :) I still struggle with Flajolet and Sedgewick though, as I find it quite dense.

Comment: You're welcome! Good to see that some answers are useful. :-) I also consider this book as a great treasure of knowledge and go again and again through some sections to deepen my understanding. I would like to additionally point to *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932/a-nice-but-somewhat-challenging-binomial-identity/2394634#2394634)* as it contains two somewhat advanced representations of binomial coefficients which prove to be sometimes helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that link, it's full of helpful tricks! The Beta function representation I have seen (I *accidentally* derived it recently) but I've not seen the residue representation and I have not seen that identity. I will read through the post but it might take me a while as my complex analysis is a little rusty. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is  a variation based upon generating functions of **Smirnov words**. These are words with no equal consecutive characters. (See example III.24 *Smirnov words* from *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html)* by Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick for more information.)

> We encode the digits 
>   \begin{align*}
> 1,2,3,4 \qquad\text{as}\qquad d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4
> \end{align*}
>   and look  for Smirnov words of length $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$ built from $d_i,1\leq i\leq 4$ with each letter occurring exactly $n_i\geq 1$ times.

A generating function for the number of Smirnov words over a four letter alphabet $V=\{d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4\}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\left(1-\frac{4z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}

We  use      the *coefficient of*  operator  $[z^n]$     to  denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a series $A(z)$. The number of all Smirnov words of length $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$ over a four letter alphabet is therefore 
\begin{align*}
\left[z^{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4}\right]\left(1-\frac{4z}{1+z}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}

> Since we want to count the number of words of length $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$ with each character in $d_i$ occurring $n_i$ times, we keep track of each character. We obtain the number of wanted words as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left[d_1^{n_1}d_2^{n_2}d_3^{n_3}d_4^{n_4}\right]\left(1-\frac{d_1}{1+d_1}-\frac{d_2}{1+d_2}-\frac{d_3}{1+d_3}-\frac{d_4}{1+d_4}\right)^{-1}}
> \end{align*}

*Example:*

We consider the example of @N.Shales setting $(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4)=(4,3,3,2)$ and we obtain in accordance with his result (and with some help of Wolfram Alpha)
\begin{align*}
\left[d_1^4d_2^3d_3^3d_4^2\right]\left(1-\frac{d_1}{1+d_1}-\frac{d_2}{1+d_2}-\frac{d_3}{1+d_3}-\frac{d_4}{1+d_4}\right)^{-1}\color{blue}{=23\,254}
\end{align*}