# Number of ways of organising objects (which are in distinct groups) in a line with constraints on segments.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

Given $n$ objects split into $K$ groups with respective sizes $h_k = \{h_1, h_2, \dots , h_K\}$, where $\sum h_k = n $, and given $\beta$ boundary points:

How many ways are there of organising the objects and boundary points in a line, such that between boundary points there are only objects of the same group, and adjacent segments cannot contain the same group?

Supplementary information:
There must be at least one object between boundary points.
There are always 2 extra implied boundary points at the start and end of the sequence.
Objects in the same group are indistinguishable.

For example, if we have $ n = 10, K = 3, h_K = \{3, 2, 5\}, \beta = 3$ :
Allowed sequences include:
AABBCCCCCA and
CCCBBAAACC
Where A, B, C represent the 3 groups.

For the case where $\beta = K - 1 $, the number of combinations can be expressed as $K!$
For the case where $\beta = n - 1 $, the number of combinations can be expressed using Smirnov Words as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2401354/1251999).

I need a closed expression that can count the number of combinations given any $K$, sizes $h_k$, and $\beta$. The expression should be able to handle large $n$ and large $K$.